# is there a such thing as: Cr-os=genericimg?

Tags: google-chrome, operating-system, chromium, google-chrome-os

This would be cool. i am making my hp notebook 15 g3 into a chromebook and would like some help.
These are the things i have tried:

> Arnoldthebat's chromium os
>
> Google official git (chromium.googlesource.com) > chromiumos > github clone [***WIP**
>   *]
>
> Google chromebook recovery usb maker
>
> Maru on git (not maruos for android)

Can i get some help on where to go for a generic system image of google's chromium os?
Thank you! - elicodes5435

Comment: I agree that something like this should be possible, I'd think maybe your BIOS might be 'not compatible' or (be missing something needed ?).  Or maybe the CPU is missing some needed ability?  If all those things you've tried have failed, maybe it's much harder than you suspect !? Have you heard of anyone who succeeded with this model of computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically speaking, [Neverware's CloudReady](https://www.neverware.com/) is the closest you'll get at this time.  The alternative Chromium OS builds are infrequently updated, and tend to get a burst of life before going stale.